# System.Security.Cryptography - Visual Basic WinForm - Visual Studio 2019 (MD5 Hash Issue)

Tags: vb.net, md5, visual-studio-2019

I have written a program that required I call System.Security.Cryptography to create a File Hash.   I'm using MD5.  However, for me to add my program to the Microsoft Store, I cannot have any code that needs elevation.  Such as the UAC that is required to call System.Security.Cryptography.

Is there a way around this?  Is it possible to create the MD5 hash on a file without breaking any MS Store rules?

I'm coding a WinForm using Visual Studio Community 2019 in Visual Basic.

Thank you in advance,

-Ron B.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a different library (possibly third-party) that will calculate MD5 hash?  To my knowledge, it's a well-known algorithm, so I would expect that something like that would exist.  If I'm wrong, you might need to implement it yourself; this might need to be done in C# because it might need to do things that aren't allowed in VB.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. I am not able to find a third party library that I can use royalty free.  I will continue to search